# How do I run multiple versions of R in Rstudio on Ubuntu?

Tags: r, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, rstudio

I have researched it a lot.

Following is the link from RStudio support:
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R

The above link doesn't help as much.
Following are my system stats:
Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
RStudio Version 0.99.491

Comment: What exactly is your problem (what have you tried so far and what are the observed symptoms)?